# Moving google cloud data between buckets in different regions without incurring egress costs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to move data from one bucket in GCP to another, say from bucket A to bucket B. These buckets are in different regions. My goal is to minimize the cost of the transfer.

Reading from: https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing ...

> Egress represents data sent from Cloud Storage in HTTP responses. Data or metadata read from a Cloud Storage bucket is an example of egress.

> Ingress represents data sent to Cloud Storage in HTTP requests. Data or metadata written to a Cloud Storage bucket is an example of ingress.

To my understanding, Ingresses are free, whereas egresses can be expensive. My impression was that writing to a bucket (from anywhere) counts as an ingress, whereas reading from a bucket counts as an egress. So: am I to understand that I can transfer data from A to B without incurring any network costs by:

1. Booting up a VM in the same region as A
2. Copying a file from A to the VM, e.g., by using `gsutil cp gs://[file on A] .`
3. Writing to B from the VM, e.g., by using `gsutil cp [the file] gs://[location on B]`

The read is within the same region of A, while the (apparently free?) write is from the region A is in to the region B is in? Does that sound right?

But then! This page https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/moving-buckets says: "Moving data between locations incurs network usage costs."; which makes sense, but seems to be in contrast to the ingress/egress reasoning above.

Comment: Review the details about ingress and egress. When a VM reads from a bucket that is ingress for the VM but egress for the bucket. The reverse when the VM writes to another bucket. This means there are two pricing factors to consider for one data transfer. Egress for one service and ingress for the other. Then there are variants such as zone based, region based, inter-region based, etc.

Comment: Great, that makes sense, thanks for the explanation. The detail that I was missing was that ingresses/egresses are also counted from the perspective of the bucket. Thanks!!

Comment: I created a videolab on Google Cloud Billing. If interested watch a few of the videos. These are produced by Google - 20 different areas to learn from: https://www.jhanley.com/videolabs/Google-Cloud-Billing/#0

Comment: Will do! Thank you, John, I'll check it out.